# convert list of lists to json object in java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have table `employee` which has the columns `EMPID`, `EMPNAME`, `EMPAGE`, `SALARY`, `ADDRESS`, `department_id` (foreign key to department_id in department) and another table `department` which has `department_id`, `name`. So I made a query

```
List<Department> deps = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Department.class).list();
```

The return vlaue is a List of Lists

I want to put the result in in JSON Object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post what have you done first.

Comment: Take a look at spring-data-rest and spring-boot -- it'll do all of this for you with minimal code

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
    List<List<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (List<Object> list : listOfLists) {
        JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray(list);
        jsonArray.put(newArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Spring then just add `produces ={"application/json"}` in your REST `@RequestMapping` and rest thing Spring will do for you